# namespace extension.. galaxy file system toolkit...gmail shell drive like utility

Tags: c#, shell-extensions

i was looking for some namespace extention to extend using c# (.net) but didn't find much help online except Galaxy Filesystem tooklkit. which are vc++ based but comes with c# and java wrapper classes... which helps me alot to start and i did.

i have extended that enough now and made installer to install. it get installed successfully but don't know why, when i open it, system get stuck... :( i thought my modified version might have some problem so i tried to run Galaxy filesystem toolkit's author original version and it responded in same way as mine do :D :(

now feeling bit helpless as even author is not responding my queries regarding my queries for some reason...

any help would be really appreciated....

FYI: i need to have Gmail drive like stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** implement shell extensions with C# or anything that uses a framework.

If you do, you will break a lot of applications!

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx) for why you must not do that.

Comment: He isn't implementing it in C#. I was thinking of using the Galaxy kit myself. Are there any alternatives? i.e. A c++ extension which can be used as a proxy for a C# app.

Comment: The latest .Net 4.0 runtime supports in process side-by-side loading of the .Net 4.0 runtime (and ALL future runtimes) with earlier .Net runtimes.

See following excerpt from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx 
"With the ability to have multiple runtimes in process with any other runtime, we can now offer general support for writing managed shell extensions—even those that run in-process with arbitrary applications on the machine."